# Trouble making UV for plane shape

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to import a shape into Unreal Engine 4, but it's giving me a lot of problems after trying to build the lighting. I think it's because my UVs are jacked up and not proper.

Thing is in blender, I can't get my shape to properly unwrap.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhdcp.jpg

The UV isn't appearing for both sides of the plane.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQkQ3.jpg

I'm wondering if that's one of the issues. Also, I don't seem to have any faces in my shape. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but no lines will appear for me to make. Also I've solidified the shape, so both front and back of the plane should be working.

Pretty lost. Any thoughts? (I'm very new to 3D modeling)

Comment: Hi. Please add images directly into the question body. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be in Front Ortho (Press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)

Go to Edit Mode

Extrude all the faces. Select the top and bottom faces

Press <kbd>U</kbd> -> select -> Project from view (Bounds)

[image]

Now jump to UV Editor and hope you get a good UV.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. This still only gives me one side of the shape in the UV editor though. I was thinking I should be having two sides represented in the UV editor, the front and the back.

Comment: You need some thickness to have both side image. Check the above answer edited